# C#-Winform - Wrong data read from SerialPort

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` to read data from a barcode scanner by USB COM port. But I read wrong data very often, I've checked parameters and I am very sure that they're correct.

Code:

```
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;

namespace SerialPortTestProject {
    public partial class Form1: Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

            SerialPort sp = new("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            sp.DataReceived += DataReceived1;
            sp.Open();
        }

        void DataReceived1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort) sender;
            byte[] data = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
            sp.Read(data, 0, sp.BytesToRead);
            string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

            WriteResult($"DataReceived1: {string.Join("-", data)} => {result}\r\n");
        }

        void WriteResult(String str) {
            BeginInvoke(new(() => { 
                textBox1.AppendText(str);
            }));
        }
    }
```

I tried to scan a barcode which data is 'PARTS-00010', and I got this:

[image: data log]

I used `UartAssist.exe` and get data as below. As you can see, even I scan very fast each time and it still gets the correct data 'PARTS-00010', and even I read more than 50 times, almost every data is correct.

[image]

Just want to know what did I miss?

Comment: If you haven't already done so, read all of the documentation for [SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) as well as the documentation for your device. The _SerialPort_ property values need to be set correctly - they need to match the settings on the device.

Comment: The barcode scanner may allow one to configure it such that it sends a newline at the end of the scan. Then set the proper value for [SerialPort.NewLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.newline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) and use [SerialPort.ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)

Comment: Also, try setting [DtrEnable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.dtrenable?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) = true and then subscribe to [SerialPort.PinChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.pinchanged?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0). This is useful when the barcode scanner is unplugged.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Guys I found a way that can avoid this issue:

Use `RJCP.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream` instead of `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`

Code like below:

```
using RJCP.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;
//using System.IO.Ports;

namespace SerialPortTestProject {
    public partial class Form1: Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

            //SerialPort sp = new("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            //sp.DataReceived += DataReceived1;
            //sp.Open();

            SerialPortStream sps = new("COM3", 9600, 8, Parity.None, StopBits.One);
            sps.DataReceived += DataReceived2;
            sps.Open();
        }

        void DataReceived1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            //SerialPort sp = (SerialPort) sender;
            //byte[] data = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
            //sp.Read(data, 0, sp.BytesToRead);
            //string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

            //WriteResult($"DataReceived1: {string.Join("-", data)} => {result}\r\n");
        }

        void DataReceived2(object? sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
            SerialPortStream sp = (SerialPortStream) sender;
            byte[] data = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
            sp.Read(data, 0, sp.BytesToRead);
            string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

            WriteResult($"DataReceived2: {string.Join("-", data)} => {result}\r\n");
        }

        void WriteResult(String str) {
            BeginInvoke(new(() => { 
                textBox1.AppendText(str);
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

And result as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXEPs.png)

I have to say it works very well and more efficient. Thanks to RJCP.

Comment: Don't know why people mark this as 'not useful', it does work for me. To be honest, I don't really know what happen here, but `RJCP.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream` did solve my problem..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;

namespace SerialPortTestProject {
    public partial class Form1: Form {
        
        private StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        //private String endBuffer = "\r";  // wrong
        private char endBuffer = (char)3    // correct

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            sp.DataReceived += DataReceived;
            sp.Open();
        }

        void DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {           
            var sp = (SerialPort) sender;   
            
            // if data exist in serial port
            while (sp.BytesToRead > 0)
            {   
                // append data to buffer
                buffer.Append(port.ReadExisting());
                
                // do it, until received endBuffer character
                String strBuffer = buffer.ToString()
                if (strBuffer.IndexOf(endBuffer) > 0)
                {
                    // parsing buffer
                    String[] strBufferArr = strBuffer.Split(endBuffer);
                    foreach (String data in strBufferArr)
                    {
                        // reject invalid data
                        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(data) || data.Length != 11) 
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        // show valid data
                        WriteResult("DataReceived1: " + data);
                    }
                                        
                    // clear buffer
                    buffer.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

        void WriteResult(String str) {
            BeginInvoke(new(() => { 
                textBox1.AppendText(str);
            }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not working, DataReceived event only fires once, it doesn't fire any more later

Comment: @StreenJiang Try change private String endBuffer = "\r";   to  char endBuffer = ((char)3);  I have corrected the code.

Comment: Yeah the event works fine now, but still getting wrong data from the sanner gun. I think I must have missed something for `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`. Anyway, I am now using `RJCP.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream` instead of previous one and somehow it works really great, barely no wrong data received, but thanks all the same. @Ihdina

Comment: @StreenJiang, add if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(data) || data.Length != 11) { continue; }  to reject invalid data, you will get valid data in here

Comment: @StreenJiang also change if (sp.BytesToRead > 0) to while (sp.BytesToRead > 0) to gets the number of bytes of data in the receive buffer.

Comment: Actually it's not about **invalid** data, it's all about **incorrect** data. Some of the receiving data are incorrect, and it's randomly, as you can see in the picture I posted.